# I need regex to modify a string

Tags: regex, string, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

can someone help me to write a regex to modify the links below

```
mywebsite.com/images/products/12345678_pit.jpg<br>
mywebsite.com/images/products/12345678_piat_a2.jpg
```

to the links:

```
mywebsite.com/images/zoomimage/12/12345678_var.jpg<br>
mywebsite.com/images/zoomimage/12/12345678_var_a2.jpg
```

we see that

- `products` = `zoomimage`
- `pit|piat` = `var`
- `12345678` = `12/12345678` (meaning first 2 digits / initial number)

Thanks

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: What's your budget? If you want us to do all the work, you don't expect it to be free, right?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal effort in solving the actual problem, including the attempted code and the encountered issues

Answer (score 1):

Giving you an example in PHP, but the regex can be reused with another language :

```
$urls = array(
    'mywebsite.com/images/products/12345678_pit.jpg',
    'mywebsite.com/images/products/23456789_foo.jpg',
    'mywebsite.com/images/products/34567890_bar.jpg',
    'mywebsite.com/images/products/12345678_piat_a2.jpg',
    'mywebsite.com/images/products/45678901_baz_a2.jpg',
    'mywebsite.com/images/products/56789012_qux_a2.jpg'
);
foreach($urls as $url) {
    echo preg_replace(
        '/products\/(\d{2})(\d*)_[a-z-]+(.*)\.jpg/i', 
        'zoomimage/$1/$1$2_var$3.jpg', $url) .'<br>';
}
// mywebsite.com/images/zoomimage/12/12345678_var.jpg
// mywebsite.com/images/zoomimage/23/23456789_var.jpg
// mywebsite.com/images/zoomimage/34/34567890_var.jpg
// mywebsite.com/images/zoomimage/12/12345678_var_a2.jpg
// mywebsite.com/images/zoomimage/45/45678901_var_a2.jpg
// mywebsite.com/images/zoomimage/56/56789012_var_a2.jpg
```